# I can not run successfuly for cucumber report

Tags: cucumber, report

I can run successfully in terminal window by command `“mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @ValidateLoggedInUser"”`
Because some the other test cases have error. So I need to `debug` to check the step and reason.
But there is error when run it in `*.feature` file.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.cucumber.listener.Reporter.loadXMLConfig(Reporter.java:56)    at
>   com.dxc.vpc.automation.glue.CucumberUtilities.extentReport(CucumberUtilities.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)  at
>   cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)     at
>   cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)  at
>   cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)    at
>   cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)   at
>   cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Comment: Could you please update your question by adding the code for your feature and step definitions (specifically the one throwing the error) and how you are running them?

Comment: Please add your runner class code